# How to repeats a layout?

Tags: android, layout, repeat

My `layout` contains a  `spinner` and an `editText`.I want this `spinner` and `editText` fields repeats 1 or 2 times in an activity based on some condition.Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `<include>` tag. [Here](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html) is good article about it. And if you want to hide them a truntime just change the visibility tag